# Print CSS generated gradient

Tags: css, printing

I have tried to search for this all over, but haven't found anything close to my question anywhere.

Does anyone know if it's possible to print out a CSS generated linear-gradient? I am mocking up a website for my boss, and it looks really nice, but when I try to make a printer-friendly page, the gradients don't display at all.

For reference, what I'm trying to print is a indicator bar that has a slider element on top of it, to indicate the result of a value within a range.

The gradients look really great on the page, but just don't show up in a print dialog.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dumb question: are you sure its not just the dialog that messes up the gradients? In other words, if you actually print the page, does it come out correct? I know once or twice the print preview was misleading on complicated css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, sounds like all background images aren't printing right?  That's a default behavior of IE.  To print background graphics (which might include your 'gradient graphic', go to print -> page setup and click on "Print background colors and images".
Hope this helps.

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to have this option but you can do the same with Firefox under the Page Setup option.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was able to finally figure out this is what is happening. Now it's time to find a workable solution. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Not exact here, but printing is rendered in it's own engine apart from the browsers engine.

It TYPICALLY (with the exception of say, the iPad) filters out background images and certain types of rendered material to save on ink. The only way to change this is if the user changes his or her own printing preferences.

There is no CSS or Javascript way to make this happen, unless you render the page as an image, and print the image.

I can go in to more detail if you'd like, but with the exception of the iPad, print formatting like eMail formatting is a tricky area to get in to.